# Conditional Formatting Not Setting Format Conditions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to write some code that changes the cell fill colour of specified groups of cells if a formula is correct. At the moment only some of the groups of cells are formatting as I intend.

Concerning the groups of cells that are not formatting as desired - when manually inspecting the Conditional Formatting Manager - the conditional formatting correctly contains the groups of cells that the formatting should be applied to, but the cell formatting has not been added. I find this surprising as at the moment the intended cell formatting is the same for all groups. I would be grateful as to some suggestions as to what I should do to solve this issue! Thank you for any comments.

Code Below:
My main program creates groups of cells that are to be formatted - these cells are stored in a variable (pathstring) and then passed to the subroutine shown. (So all the conditionally formatted groups of cells should be red, but some groups have no colour formatting at all.)

```
Sub ConditionalFormattingExample(pathstring As String)

'Define Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range(pathstring)

'Apply Conditional Formatting

MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$AN$16=5"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you want to check $AN$16 for all cells - or do you want it to be relative check? And: are there other format conditions applied to that range. It would be safer to use `set fc = myrange.formatconditions.add ...` and then use fc for the settings:  `fc.setfirstpriority`

Comment: I will not be using AN16 for all of the groups of cells in the future. I am using this now as I am trying to get the conditional formatting working!

Comment: But in your code it is fixed ($) - so all cells iin the range are running the same check

Comment: Hi - is there a problem with having this fixed cell? I believe it is just testing whether the cell AN16 has the value of 5.

Comment: yes - the result will be the same for the whole range. Maybe you should add some sample data and expected output to your question - otherwise it's hard to make suggestions. And keep the second part of my first comment in mind.

Comment: What is the length of the `pathstring` value you're passing in?  Note there's a limit to the length of the string you can pass to `Range()` - if it's too long then some cells will silently be excluded.

Comment: Tim Williams - there are no cells silently being excluded. All cells appear in the "Applies to Box" - it is only the formatting to be applied that sometimes does not get added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only conditional formatting applied then you might want to first delete any existing CF:

```vb
Sub ConditionalFormattingExample(pathstring As String)
    'ideally specify a worksheet here...
    With Range(pathstring).FormatConditions
        .Delete
        With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$AN$16=5")
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'or vbRed
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have comments to add please don't edit my answer - use comments, or if you have code to add then please edit your question and add it there.